# Find all $\alpha$ so $f$ is continuous. $f(x)= \begin{cases} x^\alpha \sin{1/x} & x>0 \\ 0 & x=0 \\ |x|^{-2\alpha} \sin{x} & \text{else} \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, functions, continuity

Find all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x^\alpha \sin{1/x} & x > 0 \\
      0 & x = 0 \\
      |x|^{-2\alpha} \sin{x} & \text{else}
   \end{cases}$

---

I'm a bit confused because to be continuous, we need to get the value $0$ as $x$ approaches zero from the left and the right. But for the case $x > 0$, we would need $\alpha > 0$, but at the same time for the case $x < 0$, wouldn't we need $\alpha < 0$ ? How is that possible ? Or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing something:

You can compute that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{\sin(x)}{|x|^{2\alpha}} = \begin{cases}
0 &\alpha<1/2,\\
-1 & \alpha=1/2,\\
\end{cases}
$$
and the limit doesn't exists for $\alpha>1/2$.

Comment: Why does it give zero for $\alpha < 1/2$ ?

Comment: @wengen, $\alpha<\frac12\Rightarrow 2\alpha<1,$ so $\beta=1-2\alpha>0$ and $$\frac{\sin(x)}{|x|^{2\alpha}}=\frac{\sin(x)}{|x|^{1-\beta}}=\frac{\sin(x)}{|x|}|x|^\beta.$$